# Getting only the models related to a Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I don't have much experience with Django (I'm using 1.3) so I have the feeling on the back of my head that this is a dumb question... But anyway:

I have models like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    public = models.BooleanField()

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderProduct')

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    expiration = models.DateField()
```

And let's say I do some query like this

```
Product.objects.filter(order__status='completed', order__user____id=2)
```

So I'd get all the products that `User2` bought (let's say it's just `Product1`). Cool. But now I want the expiration for that product, but if I call `Product1.orderproduct_set.all()` I'm gonna get every entry of `OrderProduct` with `Product1`, but I just want the one returned from my queryset.
I know I can just run a different query on OrderProducts, but that would be another hit on the database just to bring back data the query I ran before can already get. `.query` on it gives me:

```
SELECT "shop_product"."id", "shop_product"."name"
FROM "shop_product"
INNER JOIN "shop_orderproducts" ON ("shop_product"."id" = "shop_orderproducts"."product_id")
INNER JOIN "shop_order" ON ("shop_orderproducts"."order_id" = "shop_order"."id")
WHERE ("shop_order"."user_id" = 2  AND "shop_order"."status" = completed )
ORDER BY "shop_product"."ordering" ASC
```

If I could `SELECT *` instead of specific fields I'd have all the data that I need in one query. Is there anyway to build that query and get only the data related to it?

**EDIT**
I feel I need to clarify some points, I'm sorry I haven't been clearer:

1. I'm not querying against `OrderProduct` because some products are public and don't have to be bought but I still have to list them, and they'd not be returned by a query against `OrderProduct`
2. The result I'm expecting is a list of products, along with their Order data (in case they have it). In JSON, it'd look somewhat like this

   [{id: 1, order: 1, expiration: 2013-03-03, public: false},
    {id: 1, order: , expiration: , public: true

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `Product1.orderproduct_set.all()`, does it work if you do `Product1.orderproduct_set.filter(order__user__id = 2)` ?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm gonna get every entry of OrderProduct with Product1, but I just
>   want the one returned from my queryset.

You just want which "one"? Your query is filtering on the `Product` model, so all `Users`, `Orders`, and `OrderProducts` associated with each of the `Products` in the returned queryset will be accessible.

If you want one specific `OrderProduct`, then you should be filtering as `op = OrderProduct.objects.filter(xxxxx)` and then accessing the models up the chain like so:

`op.product`, `op.order`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it may not be the right way for me. See the edit on the post.

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested the method [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), but this isn't available in Django 1.3.

Dan Hoerst is right about selecting from `OrderProduct`, but that still hits the database more than necessary. We can stop that by using the [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method.

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> len(connection.queries)
0
>>> first_result = OrderProduct.objects.select_related("order__user", "product")
...               .filter( order__status="completed",
...                        order__user__pk=2 )[0]
>>> len(connection.queries)
1
>>> name = first_result.order.user.name
>>> len(connection.queries)
1
>>> product_name = first_result.product.name
>>> len(connection.queries)
1
```

Comment: `select_related` does not work against Many to Many relationships. So the benefits in this case may not be that great, and `first_result.product.name` would result in an extra query.

Comment: @DanHoerst Yes, but since we are selecting on the ‘linking’ model and not the models being joined by a M2M relationship… this will work. The number of queries will drop to one.

Comment: I've added some code, to show the number of queries being run.

Comment: Yeah, `prefetch_related` would probably be perfect... but I'm not sure I can start the query from `OrderProduct`, sice it wouldn¶t get me some products I actully need. See the EDIT up there

Comment: In that case, there is no way to achieve this in less than two queries.